# How to edit WSP file of webpart in Visual Studio

Tags: development

I want to edit the .wsp file in visual studio, please help me.

Comment: Do you have the source code? You can not edit the .wsp source code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "edit" a .wsp file directly in Visual Studio. If you want to edit the source code, you actually need the source code, not the .wsp file.

If you just want to see the contents of the file, you can rename the somefile.wsp to somefile.cab and open it. So at least you can view/get the xml-files and .dlls

The only way to get the source code out of an .wsp is reverse engineering the dll (e.g. with  [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)). But this is not recommended if the Sharepoint solution package is copyrighted (and if it's not yours or your company's development, it's most likely a sure bet that it IS copyrighted), because that may not be legal depending on the usage conditions and the country you live in.

Comment: Thanks Dolgsthrasir. I knew that .wsp to .cab conversion but can i edit the .wsp file in visual studio.In my wsp.webpart is present

Comment: I still don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Out-of-the-box it is not possible to just open the .wsp in Visual Studio and edit the content. A .wsp is nothing else but a file in .cab format SharePoint uses for deployment. If you just want to change some of the files within a .wsp, you could rename the .wsp to .cab, extract the files, do your changes and repack the files to a .cab. See this for an example [Edit SharePoint Solution wsp file manually](http://niranjanrao.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/edit-sharepoint-solution-wsp-file-manually-3/)